# SU Tag merge request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I propose that we merge [regex](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/regex) & [regexp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/regexp) with [regular-expressions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex seems like the far more commonly used tag (142 questions, vs. 1 of regular-expressions). Most people say "regex", so personally I think the other two should be merged with regex. If anyone has any comments on this, let me know, otherwise I'll perform the merge later today.

Comment: I have no strong feelings one way or the other.

Comment: If someone enters `regex` it'd automatically change to `regular-expressions`, right? I'd vote for the longer variant, as it's the "canonical" name. That's what we did for many of the product name tags, using `microsoft-foo` instead of `ms-foo` etc.

Comment: Please go with regex.

Comment: I merged into [regex] and created a synonym for [regular-expressions] .. I think [regexp] is so similar it's not worth creating a synonym over.